# Multiprocessing long running process in the background without blocking

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that simply checks a fifo and sets an event if it sees a "stop" message:

```
class Logwatch():
...
    def run_stop_check(self, stop_event):
        flagsint  = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [os.O_RDONLY, os.O_NONBLOCK])
        fifo_path = "/tmp/logwatch_fifo"
        fifo_fd = open_fifo(fifo_path, flagsint)
        with os.fdopen(fifo_fd) as fifo:
            while True:
                message = fifo.readline()
                if "stop" in message.strip():
                   logger.debug("Recieved stop request, stopping...")
                   stop_event.set()
                   break
                sleep(.1)
```

It is called in main with:

```
pool.apply_async(logwatch.run_stop_check, (stop_event,))
...
```

The idea is to call several such functions and have them all run independently of the main thread indefinitely using while True

```
pool.apply_async(logwatch.run_stop_check, (stop_event,))
pool.apply_async(something else...
pool.apply_async(another function...
```

However, even though the `run_stop_check` function should run indefinitely (`while True`), It doesn't. it runs once and then the program terminates.  I don't understand why this is, or how to make it do what I intend.

Comment: The main process needs to wait on the children. This is typically done via the `join()` method on the object returned by `apply_async`.

Comment: Also note that the `while True:` loop in the `run_stop_check()` function will terminate whenever there's a `"stop" in message.strip()` because of the `break` statement.

Comment: @martineau That is intentional.  It's supposed to exit if it has set the event.

Comment: Mark: OK, only mentioned it because it sounded like you didn't understand why the loop didn't run indefinitely.